# setRotation of layout in android

Tags: android, rotation

I'm new in android development, I'm using the setRotation method to rotate the whole layout, but I want to set the duration of the rotation

while (fromDegree < toDegree) {
    fromDegree++;
    myLayout.setRotation(fromDegree);
}

can any one please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Handler class with PostDelayed method.

Example:

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        (new Handler()).postDelayed(new splashHandler(), 2000);
    }

    class splashHandler implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {

            .....Do something.....
        }
    }
```